# How to keep the precision as the same of the original data when using csvread/dlmread and csvwrite/dlmwrite?

Tags: matlab

I am doing some data analysis using Matlab and working with txt files. I have some data of a matrix saved in a text file for example:

```
1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3

1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7

1.8,1.9,2.0,2.1

3.3,3.0,4.0,5.0
```

and I am using csvread/dlmread to read the data into Matlab as a matrix. Then I am using csvwrite/dlmwrite to write the data to a separate txt file as comma separated values.

The problem is when I write the matrix to another file, if the last digit of a value is a zero, it gets eliminated. I got the following data in the new file instead of the original matrix.

```
1,1.1,1.2,1.3

1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7

1.8,1.9,2,2.1

3.3,3,4,5
```

I am kind of losing precision. Is there a way to tell Matlab to keep exactly the same data as the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty easy.  [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) has a `'precision'` flag that you can use to specify how many digits of precision you want for the output file.  If we are assuming that your data consists of just a single digit of precision, you can do the following, assuming your matrix is stored in `M` and that your values are exactly like what we see in your sample data and you want to write to a file called `output.txt`:

```
dlmwrite('output.txt', M, 'precision', '%.1f');
```

This will print out each number with a single digit of precision.  The format specifier `%.1f` means to print out a floating point representation of your number to a single digit of precision.  If you omit `.1` and just do `%f`, the default is 5 digits of precision.

As a reproducible example, I've placed your data into a file called `testdata.txt`, then resaved it using `dlmwrite` like I did before:

```
>> in = dlmread('testdata.txt');
>> in
in =

    1.0000    1.1000    1.2000    1.3000
    1.4000    1.5000    1.6000    1.7000
    1.8000    1.9000    2.0000    2.1000
    3.3000    3.0000    4.0000    5.0000
>> dlmwrite('output.txt', in, 'precision', '%.1f');
```

... and this is what I get for the output in the file:

```
1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3
1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7
1.8,1.9,2.0,2.1
3.3,3.0,4.0,5.0
```

---

FWIW, you're not "losing any precision".  `3` and `3.0` are pretty much the same number... what you're more concerned about is formatting preference, not precision.  If you re-read that output file that truncates the decimal places for whole numbers back into MATLAB, you would see that it's still interpreting those numbers that truncate out the trailing zeroes as valid floating point numbers... i.e. `3 --> 3.0`.

Comment: The digits for original data may not be consistent, is there a way to keep the digits exactly as the original data set?

Comment: @bill - Is there a reason why?  But if you really want to... yes there is.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: So, what I was doing is not taking the entire data set but part of it. In that way I am only extracting the useful information but I do want to keep the format and precision the same. Taking the entire data set was just an example of the process. Sorry for the confusion and thanks.

Comment: @bill - I really don't see why you want to do this... artificially putting in a `.0` for whole numbers.  If you want to do that, you'd have to write each value individually which is more complicated.  I'm going to leave this for someone else to answer.